# What does "bind directly" mean in reference initialization?

Tags: c++, reference, initialization, language-lawyer

N4527 8.5.3 [dcl.init.ref]

> 5 A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as follows:

> (5.1) — [...]
>
> - (5.1.1) — [...]
> - (5.1.2) — [...]

> (5.2) — Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., cv1 shall be
> const), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference.
>
> - (5.2.1) — If the initializer expression
> - - (5.2.1.1) — is an xvalue (but not a bit-field), class prvalue, array prvalue or function lvalue and “cv1 T1”
>     is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”, or
> - - (5.2.1.2) — has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not reference-related to T2, and can be
>     converted to an xvalue, class prvalue, or function lvalue of type “cv3 T3”, where “cv1 T1” is
>     reference-compatible with “cv3 T3” (see 13.3.1.6),
>
> then the reference is bound to the value of the initializer expression in the first case and to
> the result of the conversion in the second case (or, in either case, to an appropriate base class
> subobject).
>
> - (5.2.2) — Otherwise:
> - - (5.2.2.1) — If T1 or T2 is a class type and T1 is not reference-related to T2, user-defined conversions
>     are considered using the rules for copy-initialization of an object of type “cv1 T1” by userdefined
>     conversion (8.5, 13.3.1.4, 13.3.1.5); the program is ill-formed if the corresponding non-reference copy-initialization would be ill-formed. The result of the call to the conversion
>     function, as described for the non-reference copy-initialization, is then used to direct-initialize
>     the reference. For this direct-initialization, user-defined conversions are not considered.
> - - (5.2.2.2) — Otherwise, a temporary of type “cv1 T1” is created and copy-initialized (8.5) from the initializer
>     expression. The reference is then bound to the temporary.
> - - If T1 is reference-related to T2:
> - - (5.2.2.3) — cv1 shall be the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv2 ; and
> - - (5.2.2.4) — if the reference is an rvalue reference, the initializer expression shall not be an lvalue.

> In all cases except the **last** (i.e., creating and initializing a temporary from the initializer expression), the
> reference is said to **bind directly** to the initializer expression.

What does the "last case" mean? 5.2.2(includes 5.2.2.1 and 5.2.2.2) or 5.2.2.2(just one)?

In other words, is 5.2.2.1 binding directly?

```
//case 5.2.1.2
struct X{};

struct Y{Y(X);};
const Y& y = X();   // bind directly

struct Z{operator X();};
const X& x = Z();   // bind directly

//case 5.2.2.1
struct A{operator int();};
const int& a = A(); // bind directly or not?

struct B{B(int);};
const B& b = 1;     // bind directly or not?
```

Comment: In the last two snippets in your example, either `T1` or `T2` is of class type. Therefore 5.2.2.2 doesn't apply (it *does* bind directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "last case" is referring to 5.2.2.2:

> — Otherwise, a temporary of type `“cv1 T1”` is created and copy-initialized (8.5) from the initializer expression. The reference is then bound to the temporary.

This case is contingent on the previous condition being false, which is 5.2.2.1:

> — If `T1` or `T2` is a class type and `T1` is not *reference-related* to `T2`...

This isn't the case for the last two snippets of your example since in the first one `A` is of class type and `int` is *not* reference-related to `A`. In the second example, `B` is of class type and `B` is not reference-related to `int`. Since these are false 5.2.2.2 doesn't apply (they *do* bind directly).